# Changing the default camera of Android on an application

Tags: android

There is an application which is defaultly(only) using the back-rear camera.
I want to use front camera on this application.

Is there any way to change it ?
There is no button or something on the application to change to camera.

or is there any option to disable the rear camera on Android? Then the application may use the front camera.

ps: it's not my own application, did not coded by me. I downloaded it from playstore.

Comment: If you didn't code it. Than, how can we help without seeing any source code? So, easily I will say that this doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to change camera of another application using our application. Not at all